# Oracle Listagg Overflow truncate on the begining

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, listagg

I have a question about the function listagg in Oracle
I would like when the listagg exceeds the limit concatenation of 4000 characters to truncate the extra characters.

I have found that there is the clause ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE '...', but is it possible to add the '...' at the start of the concatenation and keep only the 4000 characters ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you illustrate the question? I can't imagine what you are saying. No need to use all 4000 characters; make it simple, just *show* us what you want.

Comment: This is described in [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466): ***ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE** If you specify this clause, then the function returns a truncated list of measure values. The `truncation_indicator` designates the string that is to be appended to the truncated list of measure values. If you omit this clause, then the truncation indicator is an ellipsis (`...`).*

Comment: I mean that instead of having 'word1 word2 word3 ...' I would like to have '... word1 word2 word3'

Comment: No, it *appends*. (I've never thought about what it should do for a right-to-left language...). You would probably have to test for `...` at the end, remove it with `substr`, and re-add it to the start - but only if it's there, e.g. with a case expression.

Comment: @prokopis So you want to tail the input and add overflow marker from the beginning instead of showing starting portion of the value, right? Or you really want just move the dots to the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the string is going to overflow and, if so, remove the overflow characters from the end and prepend them to the string:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN SUM(LENGTH(value) + LENGTH(',')) - LENGTH(',') > 4000
       THEN '...'
            || SUBSTR(
                 LISTAGG(value, ',' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE '...' WITHOUT COUNT)
                   WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value),
                 1,
                 3997
               )
       ELSE LISTAGG(value, ',' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE '...' WITHOUT COUNT)
              WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value)
       END AS list
FROM   table_name
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/x6lpULXr)

Comment: If I was a user who see this result I would expect `... something` to show me the ending of some long text, but the above code just moves ellipsis. Though, I completely understand that this is exactly what was requested and this should be addressed to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is appending the text you want at the start also at the end of the '...' and trim that text again before concatenating it with the start text.

So: 'starttext:' || regexp_replace(listagg ....    ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE '... and more. starttext') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a)  ,'(.*)( starttext)$','\1')